# Probability of first player winning in an urn game?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An urn has $W$ white and $B$ black balls. Players 1 and 2 alternate drawing balls without replacement. A player wins (and the game ends) when one of the players has drawn $N<=B$ black balls for some specified $N$.

I know if $N$ and $B$ are one and the total number of balls is even, it's 0.5, but I'm not sure how to approach this for larger $N$ and $B$.

How does one go about this?

Comment: I am not clear as to what exactly you are asking.  How does a player win ?

Comment: "I know if $N$ is $1$ and the total number of balls is even, its $0.5$..."  Do you though?  If player one goes first, surely his chances of winning are better than player two's except in the case that $W=B=1$.  I assume once a player wins they stop playing with no chance for a tie.  Take for counterexample $B=W=2$ and $N=1$.  Player one could win on the first turn with probability $0.5$, or he could miss, second player miss, and him win on turn three with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{6}$, for a total probability of winning as $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @trueblueanil: Say there are 10 black and 30 white in the urn. With $N$ specified as say 3, it's the first player to have drawn a total of 3 blacks.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Huh? If there's only one black and an even number of balls total, each player has 0.5 probability of drawing that black. Oh - I think I see the crossed wires - I meant if $B$ is one... sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If $B=2,N=1$, the chance of the first player winning is:
$$\frac2{W+2}+\frac{W}{W+2}\frac{W-1}{W+1}\frac2W+\frac{W(W-1)(W-2)(W-3)2}{(W+2)(W+1)W(W-1)(W-2)}+\cdots\\
=\frac2{(W+2)(W+1)}\left((W+1)+(W-1)+(W-3)+...\right)\\
=\frac{W+2}{2W+2}\,\text{ (W even), or }\frac{W+3}{2W+4}\text{ (W odd)}$$
This is the same chance for $W=2k$ and $W=2k-1$.

For $B=3,N=1$, I get 
$$\frac12+\frac3{4(W+2)}\,\text{(W odd), or }\frac12+\frac3{8(W+1)}+\frac3{8(W+3)}\,\text{(W even)}$$

EDIT: The result for $N=1$, general $B$ and $W$, seems to be the following if $W$ is odd:
$$\frac12+\frac B{2^B}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{B/2}\frac{B-1\choose2k-1}{W+2k}\right)$$
and the following if $W$ is even:
$$\frac12+\frac B{2^B}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{(B-1)/2}\frac{B-1\choose2k}{W+2k+1}\right)$$
It might be possible to prove them by induction, using 
$$P(B,W,1)=\frac B{B+W}+\frac W{B+W}(1-P(B,W-1,1))$$

Comment: Thanks for the work, +1. I've been attacking the $N$=2 case, appear to have found a form (ugly sum of sums of binomial coefficient machinations) that works for every case I've tested. After more testing/cleanup and perhaps poking at if it extends to $N$>2 cases, will add to question, perhaps to prompt ideas. It is basically taking the tack of calculating the probability of the win happening on the $Kth$ draw, and summing for odd/even $K$ for the respective players.